# Regex Pattern containing single spaces but no leading or trailing spaces?

Tags: java, regex, trim

I am trying to define a string that a user can enter into the system using Regex in Java. The string should not contain trailing, leading or double spaces but may contain numerous spaces throughout the string name. It should only contain a defined set of other characters, the allowed character set is `([0-9a-zA-Z_\\+=\\(\\)<>]+)`.

Is there a way to define no trailing, leading or double spaces in a string, not using '\S' as this will then allow any character?

I have tried replacing the double spaces using

`String file1 = file.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");` which works but then `file1.trim()` or

```
file1 = file1.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
file1 = file1.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

does not replace the trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: Use `Pattern` and `Matcher`. See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regexjava).

Comment: String.trim() will remove all whitespace type characters from the beginning and end. If it's not something else is wrong or those are some other type of special char just displaying as whitespace..

Comment: `System.out.println("\"" + ("  ab   c   ".replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\s+$", "")) + "\"");` -> `"ab c"`; looks fine to me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Pattern` as what @Stephan mentioned. But, if you just want to do something really straightforward, I think you are basically on the right track... just do a trim() before replaceAll(..):-

```
public String clean(String s) {
    return s.trim().replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ");
}

@Test
public void testClean() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("A B", clean("  A  B"));
    assertEquals("A B", clean("A  B  "));
    assertEquals("A B", clean("A B"));
    assertEquals("A B C", clean("  A  B C  "));
}
```